# Unresolved dependencies in sbt 0.13.1 while building basic scala 2.12.8 project using akka 2.5.24

Tags: scala, sbt, akka

Well, I have to do a client-server program in Scala for my Computers Networks's class. I'm in the begginng, just trying to compile some hello world in Scala 2.12.8 using the akka 2.5.24 (because it has network facilities). But I'm having trouble with unresolved dependencies when I execute `$ sbt run` with sbt 0.13.1.

In this task, I'm trying to run just the code below in Fedora 30. I've already tried to change scala and akka versions, remove `~/.sbt` and `~/.iv2` and use another sbt version (1.2.8). All of the attempts were unsuccessful. Below I show an attempt with sbt 0.13.1.

The scala code:

```scala
import akka.actor.{ Actor, ActorRef, Props }
import akka.io.{ IO, Tcp }
import akka.util.ByteString
import java.net.InetSocketAddress
```

The sbt configuration:

```
name := "scala-transfer-file"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.8"

resolvers += "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-actor" % "2.5.24"
```

I was just awaiting a sucess message or something, as it is just importation of packages. But what I'm getting is

```
[info] Set current project to scala-transfer-file (in build file:/home/canmarshavelife/git/scala-transfer-file/)
[info] Updating {file:/home/canmarshavelife/git/scala-transfer-file/}scala-transfer-file...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor;2.5.24 ...
[warn]  module not found: com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor;2.5.24
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/canmarshavelife/.ivy2/local/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor/2.5.24/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== fedora: tried
[warn]   file:/usr/share/sbt/ivy-local/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor/2.5.24/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/akka/akka-actor/2.5.24/akka-actor-2.5.24.pom
[warn] ==== sonatype-snapshots: tried
[warn]   https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/typesafe/akka/akka-actor/2.5.24/akka-actor-2.5.24.pom
[warn] ==== Typesafe Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/akka/akka-actor/2.5.24/akka-actor-2.5.24.pom
[info] Resolving org.sonatype.oss#oss-parent;9 ...
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.12.8/scala-library-2.12.8.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.12.8!scala-library.jar (8567ms)
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.12.8/scala-compiler-2.12.8.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.12.8!scala-compiler.jar (11382ms)
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.12.8/scala-reflect-2.12.8.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.12.8!scala-reflect.jar (3136ms)
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/modules/scala-xml_2.12/1.0.6/scala-xml_2.12-1.0.6.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang.modules#scala-xml_2.12;1.0.6!scala-xml_2.12.jar(bundle) (2030ms)
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/jline/jline/2.14.6/jline-2.14.6.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] jline#jline;2.14.6!jline.jar (1226ms)
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor;2.5.24: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor;2.5.24: not found
        at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:213)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:122)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:121)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:116)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:116)
        at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:104)
        at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:51)
        at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:60)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:98)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:81)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:102)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:102)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:11)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:10)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withFileLock(Locks.scala:102)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:62)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:52)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:38)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:60)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:101)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:97)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:116)
        at sbt.IvyActions$.update(IvyActions.scala:121)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1161)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1159)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$73.apply(Defaults.scala:1182)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$73.apply(Defaults.scala:1180)
        at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:35)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1184)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1179)
        at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:45)
        at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1187)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1152)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1130)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
        at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
        at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
        at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor;2.5.24: not found
[error] Total time: 39 s, completed 19/08/2019 15:24:08
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-actor" % "2.5.24"
```

to

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.5.24"
```

This is clearly [documented](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/index-actors.html#dependency). The `%%` causes sbt to add the Scala version to the artifact name (`"akka-actor"`).

Comment: You're right, sorry about my inattention. But it didn't solve the problem at all, now I get the following error: https://pastebin.com/fXgRZ28u . Do you know how to solve, please? Ps: now apparently I'm using sbt 1.2.8 apparently.